# how does hyphenation with babel-french work?

Tags: hyphenation, babel-french

I have seen number other questions dealing with this problem but never understood how it works and how to fix it.

I installed latex with the `install-tl` script and selected the `babel-french` package.

In my document I use `\usepackage[french]{babel}` but I get the following warning (and no hyphenation is working):

```
No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel) the language `French' into the format.
(babel) Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel) rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel) preloaded for \language=nohyphenation instead.
```

I have no clue how to "configure my TeX system". When I look into `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/french.ldf` I see in the header

```
%% This is file `french.ldf',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% frenchb.dtx  (with options: `french')
%% This is a generated file part of the babel-french bundle
%% to be used with the Babel system.
```

and then later lines dealing with hyphenation

```
\def\FB@nopatterns{%
   \ifdefined\l@nohyphenation
      \adddialect\l@french\l@nohyphenation
      \edef\bbl@nulllanguage{\string\language=nohyphenation}%
   \else
      \edef\bbl@nulllanguage{\string\language=0}%
      \adddialect\l@french0
   \fi
   \@nopatterns{French}}
\ifdefined\l@french \else \FB@nopatterns \fi
\ifdefined\l@acadian
  \adddialect\l@canadien\l@acadian
\else
  \adddialect\l@acadian\l@french
  \adddialect\l@canadien\l@french
\fi
\providehyphenmins{french}{\tw@\thr@@}
\providehyphenmins{acadian}{\tw@\thr@@}
```

Some forums advised to run `fmtutil --all` but it does not solve anything and I do not understand what it's supposed to do from the doc (`man fmtutil`). I have the impression that LaTeX is an aging and complex system that has a lot of border effects and is thus hard to manage without deep understanding of its behavior.

Comment: Did you do a *complete* install?

Comment: As egreg says it sounds more like you either didn't make a full installation. I haven't seen a missing hyphernation pattern issue in more than 10 years. Fmtutil builds the latex formats, basically precompiling a lot of base macros so they run faster. This includes the hyphernation patterns

Comment: Additional what exactly do you mean by "I installed latex with the install-tl script and selected the babel-french package"? What exactly did you install?

Comment: When running the `install-tl` script, there is a TUI allowing to select "collections" to install. In these collections, there is a `French` collection. I installed this collection but got the hyphenation problem. So you mean there is an other collection I need to install for it to work? A full install is long and heavy, I would rather install only the packages I need for hyphenation.

Comment: I re-did the installation as I did before and it's now working mysteriously. Maybe the download did not finish last time, I will never know. Thanks for pointing me to the installation process, I would not have fixed it otherwise :)